# How to enable OSM map in Garmin?

Tags: openstreetmap, gps, garmin

I've installed two OSM maps, but I cannot use them in Garmin. See the window of Utilities / Manage Map Products:

[image]

The maps are not lockable, but I cannot use them in Garmin... What shall I do to be able to upload them to my GPS? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add some more details: How did you register the maps, do they show up in MapSetToolkit, do they show up in MapSource (which version?) and/or BaseCamp, do you use MapInstall to transfer the maps to the unit, or do you use the Windows Explorer, which Garmin model?